# Form inside an iframe does not work when submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello and sorry for the bother. I have an issue. I have this user view with the columns, left column will show the users list, and after clicking on a user, on the right side it will open in an iframe another view with a form inside it.

[image]
If I do the changes I want, then press the forms submit button (save) it will give me this error:

[image]

The code for the full view is:

```
<div style="align-content:center">
                    <div class="row" style="height:500px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <table border="1" align="center" style="margin-top:0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>User List</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;">Active</th>
                                </tr>

                                @foreach (var member in members)
                                {
                                    var memberID = Int32.Parse(member.GetProperty("memberTypeID").ToString());
                                    var ApprovedMember = ApplicationContext.Services.MemberService.GetById(memberID).IsApproved;

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a style="text-decoration: underline;" href="@Url.Action("UserManageView", "AccountSurface", new { id = member.Id })" target="liqManaging">
                                                <span>@member.Name</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>

                                        @if (ApprovedMember)

                                        {
                                            <td align="center">Yes</td>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <td align="center">No</td>
                                        }
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div name="liqManaging" class="col-sm-6">
                            <iframe name="liqManaging" runat="server"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And the code for the iframe form is:

```
<body style="padding-top:0px;">
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<AccountSurfaceController>("ManageUsers", null, new { id = "UserManageForm", enctype = "form-data" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="member" name="member" value="@userID" />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>User selected</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @memberContentNode.Name.ToString()
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @{
                    if (!ApprovedMember)
                    {
                        using (Html.BeginForm("ResendActivationNotificationForLiqAdmin", "Registration", new { id = "userResendActivationForm" }, FormMethod.Post, new { style = "display:inline" }))
                        {
                            <input type="hidden" id="Key" name="Key" value="@memberKey" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="memberEmail" name="memberEmail" value="@memberEmail" />
                            <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" style="display:inline-block">Resend activation e-mail</button>
                        }
                    }

                    using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<AccountSurfaceController>("DeleteUser", null, new { id = "userDeleteForm", style = "display:inline" }, FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" id="memberNodeId" name="memberNodeId" value="@memberID" />
                        <button class="btn-primary" id="memberEmail" name="memberEmail" value="@memberEmail" style="display:inline-block">DELETE</button>
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Save Changes
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="submit" name="submit" value="">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="1" style="margin-top:20px;" align="right">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="assignedCheckAll" value="check all" />
                Liquidation(s) managing
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var liquidation in liquidations)
        {
            if (memberAssignLiquidations.Contains(liquidation.Id.ToString()))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="assignedLiqs" name="assignedLiqs" value="@liquidation.Id" />
                        <a href="@liquidation.NiceUrl">@liquidation.Name</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>

    <table border="1" style="margin-top:20px;" align="right">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="availableCheckAll" />
                Available Liquidation(s)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var liquidation in liquidations)
        {
            if (!memberAssignLiquidations.Contains(liquidation.Id.ToString()))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="availableLiqs" name="availableLiqs" value="@liquidation.Id" />
                        <a href="@liquidation.NiceUrl">@liquidation.Name</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
}
```

Questions is: Is there a way to make this work or is there a substitution for the iframe?

Thank you all for the time and sorry for the (probably) stupid question!

Comment: I know pictures are worth a thousand words, but code is worth a lot more than the pictures.  Please share your code.  No one is going to want to guess why it isn't working.

Comment: woops forgot about that :D

Comment: hi cosmin, does your code work if you display- and submit it without the frame? where does the Html.BeginUmbracoForm<> come from ?

Comment: @floscheiwiller it worked before as I had it on a separate page (was a whole different page with the forms and did pass to the controller, did the action and came back successfully). But now I wanted to have this section on the same page as the user list.

Comment: according to your template, you generate nested forms. check if the rendered html is valid

Comment: @floscheiwiller are you referring to "beginform" and "beginumbracoform" inside the big "beginumbracoform"? As I said, before it was the same code and it worked. I did comment now those forms and only keep the big one, make it the single form and still get the error... the iframe screws it up some how... still wondering if I could use something else instead of iframe..